# Emulator not running OpenGL app which messages "Unfortunately, OpenGL ES 2.0 Basic has stopped"

Tags: android, opengl-es, android-emulator

I have obtained an example of OpenGl through [the developer site.](http://developer.android.com/training/graphics/opengl/index.html)

My problem is that it doesn't run the application.

Here is my logcat:

```
10-17 14:43:12.574: E/Trace(684): error opening trace file: No such file or directory (2)
10-17 14:43:13.523: D/libEGL(684): Emulator without GPU support detected. Fallback to software renderer.
10-17 14:43:13.523: D/libEGL(684): loaded /system/lib/egl/libGLES_android.so
10-17 14:43:13.573: I/Choreographer(684): Skipped 44 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-17 14:43:13.643: D/gralloc_goldfish(684): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
10-17 14:43:13.653: W/dalvikvm(684): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
10-17 14:43:13.653: E/AndroidRuntime(684): FATAL EXCEPTION: GLThread 78
10-17 14:43:13.653: E/AndroidRuntime(684): java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No configs match configSpec
10-17 14:43:13.653: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$BaseConfigChooser.chooseConfig(GLSurfaceView.java:863)
10-17 14:43:13.653: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$EglHelper.start(GLSurfaceView.java:1024)
10-17 14:43:13.653: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.guardedRun(GLSurfaceView.java:1401)
10-17 14:43:13.653: E/AndroidRuntime(684):  at android.opengl.GLSurfaceView$GLThread.run(GLSurfaceView.java:1240)
10-17 14:43:14.233: I/Choreographer(684): Skipped 83 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-17 14:43:16.963: I/Choreographer(684): Skipped 260 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
10-17 14:43:16.963: I/Process(684): Sending signal. PID: 684 SIG: 9
```

What I have tried:

- I searched online and found someone able to do it by setting up GPU emulation as yes
- Updated my AVD emulator

How my emulator is setup:

- Target-4.1.2. - API Level 16
- ARM(armeabi-v7a)
- Size: 1000mib
- Skin: Default(WVGA800)
- Hardware: MaxVm:48 ; Abstracted LCD density:240; Device ram size:512; GPU emulation:yes;

Can someone help me fix this issue?

I want to add that I am using Eclipse and I tried re-installing everything(Eclipse and SDK) still no luck.

Comment: I'm not sure why it's saying "Emulator with no GPU support", when you've explicitly enabled gpu support. Are you sure that the emulation option is set, that you didn't accidentally cancel it or something? Do you have proper opengl drivers installed on the emulator host machine?

Comment: Sorry for the late response.I didn't cancel it. I am not certain as all I did was installed all recommended items on the android SDK manager. The items I didn't install on 4.1.2 are Google APIs and Intel x86 Atom System Image.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Emulator GPU pass-through is not stable, I recommend using a real device.
It randomly crashed my OpenGL ES 2.0 apps on both Win7 (Intel GPU) and Ubuntu (nVidia GPU).

As you see it reports that it can't detect OpenGL and falls back to software renderer.

Comment: Giving you the point seems like no one else can provide a better answer than what you got.

Answer (score 0):

I tried the exact same steps and i was able to run it here. I could see a Greenish Triangle.

Ensure that you are building the project with API level 14 (That's what i did)

Also try the classical step of recreating the AVD.